# ツイッターのAPIの使用について

Tags: api, twitter

ツイッターのAPIを使用してユーザIDをクロールしようと考えています．
１アカウントでは15分に15回までのリクエストしか行うことができないため，
複数のアカウントを作成して，並行してクローリングすることを考えたのですが，
これは行うことは可能なのでしょうか？
理論的に行えるかどうか，ツイッターのルール的に行えるかどうかを答えていただきたいです．

Comment: もし、user_timelineのことであればレートリミットはもっと多いですが、別に直近3200件まで取得可能な制約があるため深く遡るのが目的ならばそもそも無理、という話になりますね https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.twitter.com/ja/developer-terms/agreement-and-policy

「II.B. レートリミット」に

> 開発者は、Twitter APIのアクセス、呼び出し、および使用に関する制限 (以下、「レートリミット」といいます) を超過または回避する試みを行わない

とあるので、ルール的にアウトですね。

Comment: なるほど・・・ありがとうございます．